# javascript how to use "continue" in if short expression

Tags: javascript

Do you know how to integrate "continue" in this expression?

```
arr1[i] != arr2[i] ? false : continue ;
```

Thank you !

Comment: Ternaries combine multiple expressions. `continue` is a statement, not an expression. Thus, you need to use `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) is a statement.

Inside of an [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) Javascript expect an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions). Beside that, you take an expression without using it.

---

You need an `if` statement with another statement.

```
if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]) continue;
```